# Show SQL result row in context of others

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a [query](https://aws-partners-singapore.vercel.app/partners?sql=select+launch_rank%2C+partner_info+from+summary+WHERE+%22partner_info%22+LIKE+%22%25ThoughtWorks%25%22) showing how a particular entry ranks:

```
select launch_rank, partner_info from summary WHERE "partner_info" LIKE "%Example%"
```

However it's only useful in context when it is ranked together with:

[image: Ranked with others]

How do I show the entry with 10 competitors on either side of it? Without resorting to static queries like `WHERE launch_rank > 140 and launch_rank < 200`?

Comment: I'm a bit confused.  `launch_rank()` appears to have duplicates.  What results do you want?  What does the highlighted row have to do with the query?

Comment: Please rephrase your question by showing sample starting data along with the output you expect, and also explain the logic behind that output.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have one row that you are comparing to *and* the ranks are actually different on each row, you can use:

```
with onerow as (
      select launch_rank
      from summary 
      where partner_info LIKE '%Example%'
     )
select s.*
from (select s.*
      from summary s 
      where s.launch_rank <= (select launch_rank from onerow)
      order by s.launch_rank desc
      limit 11
     ) s
union all
select s.*
from (select s.*
      from summary s 
      where s.launch_rank > (select launch_rank from onerow)
      order by s.launch_rank asc
      limit 10
     ) s
```

Comment: Thanks! Though "Example" doesn't appear in the results

Comment: @hendry . . . use can use `<=` in the first query and `limit 11`.

Answer (score 0):

Just join the table to itself:

```
select A.launch_rank, A.partner_info from summary A INNER JOIN summary B 
    ON A.launch_rank>=B.launch_rank-10 AND A.launch_rank<=B.launch_rank+10
   WHERE B."partner_info" LIKE '%Example%'
```

Comment: hmm, I have a syntax error around "launch_rank+10" I'm testing around https://aws-partners-singapore.vercel.app/partners

Comment: Nevermind ! An issue with the runner https://github.com/simonw/datasette/issues/1148